# Pod in k8s fails to connect to database with name resolution error

Tags: database, kubernetes, deployment, dns

I want to deploy a service and a postgres database in k8s. The deployment runs fine on one computer put fails on another one.
The pod database logs are fine. This is the message I get in the service that tries to connect to the database:

```
...
raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "sbdb-0.sbdb" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Inspecting the pod shows the following:

```
    lev@gpusrv01:~$ sudo kubectl describe pod sb-6d5677f566-4qmmf
Name:         sb-6d5677f566-4qmmf
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gpusrv01/10.200.3.64
Start Time:   Sat, 04 Mar 2023 10:58:33 +0100
Labels:       app=servicebroker-app
              db=sbdb
              name=sb-pod
              pod-template-hash=6d5677f566
Annotations:  sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: true
Status:       Running
IP:           10.42.0.193
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.0.193
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sb-6d5677f566
Containers:
  sb:
    Container ID:  containerd://d713eb355a0dafd9dcf9b7da6bdd5b6b1cca55147846af9f68a94e595614df4b
    Image:         sb
    Image ID:      sha256:3dc49d5c108e81948af187d2ad00f85d6b1831b8061ca79f1f3ca44a29955054
    Ports:         5000/TCP, 5000/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      flask
      run
      --host=0.0.0.0
      --port=5000
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sat, 04 Mar 2023 10:58:33 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Readiness:      http-get http://:5000/heliports delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables from:
      sb-env-list  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
      FLASK_APP:    app.py
      DB_USER:      <set to the key 'DB_USER' in secret 'servicebroker-secrets'>      Optional: false
      DB_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'DB_PASSWORD' in secret 'servicebroker-secrets'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:         <none>
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:            <none>
QoS Class:          BestEffort
Node-Selectors:     <none>
Tolerations:        node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                    node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                      From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                     ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  3m19s (x18830 over 46h)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.42.0.193:5000/heliports": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Inspecting the service sb shows the following:

```
lev@gpusrv01:~$ sudo kubectl describe svc sb
Name:                     sb
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=servicebroker-app
                          name=sb
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=servicebroker-app,db=sbdb,name=sb-pod
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.176.221
IPs:                      10.43.176.221
Port:                     http  5000/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30050/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I use the following config for the connection to the DB:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sb-env-list
data:
  DEMO_MODE: 'False'
  DB_HOST: sbdb-0.sbdb
  DB_NAME: servicebroker
  DB_PORT: "5432"
  LOG_LEVEL: "info"
  KAFKA_ADDRESS: kk-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kk.svc.cluster.local:9092
  MRM_ADDRESS: "http://mrm:5001"
```

Is the DNS config somehow broken?

Comment: Is it possible to provide more information, such as POD, some information of SVC, PG connection string, etc.?

Comment: I have just updated my question...

Comment: I tried to check the DNS health using guidance here https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v6/admin/install/cp_prereq_kubernetes_dns.html,
it looks like there is an issue:

`kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default

Server:    10.43.0.10
Address 1: 10.43.0.10


nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `DB_HOST: sbdb-0.sbdb` is wrong, since your svc's `name: sb` so it should be `DB_HOST: sb` if in same namespace and `DB_HOST: sb.default.svc.cluster.local`